# Point not works from string to double

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, double

Hi. I am trying to create a calculator and when I'm trying to use point it does not work. When I click on the point button all other numbers gets deleted and the point stays in the beginning.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPoint:(id)sender {
    if (self.statusMode == false) {
        winMargin.text = [winMargin.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
        winMarginString = winMargin.text;
        winMarginInt = [winMarginString doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"%@", winMargin.text); // .
        NSLog(@"%.20f", winMarginInt); // Gives back 0.00000000000000000000
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender {
    if (self.statusMode == false) {
        winMargin.text = [winMargin.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
        winMarginString = winMargin.text;
        winMarginInt = [winMarginString doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"%@", winMargin.text);
        NSLog(@"%.20f", winMarginInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `winMarginInt`? If it's an `int` as the name says, are you traying to assign a `double` to a `int`?

Comment: no sorry it double i just have not changed its name @LucasEduardo

Answer (score 0):

winMargin.text is not mutable so it gets overwritten.

you need NSMutableString  to store your text and then append.

Example:

```
NSMutableString *str=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
str=winMargin.text
winMargin.text=[str stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
```

Comment: Doesn't [@"string1" stringByAppendingString:@"string2"] just create a new instance of NSString?

Comment: normal NSString is mutable already in the context that you are saying it should be used, the mutable part of it is like addObject:charValue and it will add it to the string, and you should test the string to make sure it is a valid string and you can't turn 3. into a double 3 can be a double and 3.0 can be a double but not 3.

Comment: If NSString is mutable, what is the use of NSMutableString class? O.o

Comment: From NSString documentation:
"The NSString class declares the programmatic interface for an object that manages immutable strings. An immutable string is a text string that is defined when it is created and subsequently cannot be changed."

Comment: In the statement `winMargin.text = [winMargin.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];`, you are creating a new NSString from the getter of `winMargin.text` and using the setter `winMargin.text` to create a new NSString with the "." appended to the original text of the the field.

Comment: I have the same problem, nothing happend when i tried to use NSMUTABLESTRING, the same happens, all numbers in the string gets deleted and the "point" stays i the string alone @ChristianDiLorenzo